# How to keep background full height when window is resized

Tags: css

I have a website with a cover image.
The problem is when a user resizes the window, the background does not stay fixed and full height.

What I want:
A way for the background image to stay fixed and full height whilst the user resizes the window.

This is what I have so far:

```
#top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  background-image: url(http://www.kohmooksivalairesort.com/include/gallery/slide/13393910371.jpg);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h64vyr60/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

Just need to set background size as cover, and add a media query:

```css
#top{
 width: 100%;
 height:200px;
 border-bottom:1px solid black;
background-image: url(http://www.kohmooksivalairesort.com/include/gallery/slide/13393910371.jpg);
 background-size: contain;
 background-position: top center;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-attachment:fixed;
}
@media screen and (max-width:900px) {
  #top{ background-size: 900px auto;} //900px is the image original width
}
```

```html
<div id="top"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hwzhsrer/

Answer (score 0):

You can just keep `background-size` set to `initial`, or remove `background-size` property. This will retain the image height when the page is resized.

```css
#top{
 width: 100%;
 height:200px;
 border-bottom:1px solid black;
background-image: url(http://www.kohmooksivalairesort.com/include/gallery/slide/13393910371.jpg);
 background-size: initial;
 background-position: top center;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="top"></div>
```

Hope that helps you out!

Comment: oh, thank you! initial is nice, but I want to keep image with 100% screen size and stay fixed on resize. Initial don't keep my image covering all the screen size.

Comment: Ah. You didn't state it needed to be 100% screen size. Achieve this with `background-size: cover`. However, your image may get stretched slightly and may need some editing. You'll also need to make your `<div>` full screen size. You can do this in multiple ways such as using `position: fixed` with top, left, right and bottom set to `0px`. It depends on what the rest of your content is and the plan for what you want to do with it in terms of behaviour and layout.